# Switching Raspberry Pi 5V with GPIO pin

Tags: transistors, raspberry-pi

I'm switching a 24V appliance using an [IRLZ44NPbF](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irlz44npbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153567217c32725) MOSFET. This works when using an Arduino's pins because they can output 5V, a Raspberry Pi's GPIO pins are however limited to 3.3V.

Since the 5V GPIO pins on the Raspi are sufficient, but cannot be switched via software, my plan is to switch this with one of its GPIO pins, and then use that signal to control the IRL44N. However, I need another transistor for that. Is there a standard solution/component for this situation?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a typical MOSFET driver. There are many that accept 3.3v of logic input and can be powered with 5V of supply by the Raspberry Pi.

I would suggest using the [TC4427](https://www.mouser.it/datasheet/2/268/MCHPS05667_1-2520852.pdf), which has a minimum high input logic of 2.4V and a wide supply voltage range of 4.5V to 18V.

Please check the linked datasheet to make sure that the component would match with your system. Otherwise, there are many MOSFET drivers, which you can find easily on Mouser/Digikey/etc.

I hope that I have been helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If the switching is satisfactory with the 5V Arduino pin you could get something similar by cascading two inverters in a 74HCT04:

[image]

The "HCT" version is made to work with 5V TTL input levels (real bipolar TTL) which makes it compatible with 3.3V CMOS. Power supply on the inverter is 5V.

This drives the gate with some tens of mA compared to hundreds of mA or more with a "real" gate driver, but adequate for relatively infrequent switching and relatively low current loads in relation to the MOSFET size.

Answer (score 1):

The "standard" solution, using an extra transistor looks like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4gRam.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R2 keeps Q1 switched on, and therefore M1 off, in the absence of any signal applied at IN.